# How to implement many-to-many relationships in Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to relate SonataMediaBundle to another Entity: **Products** with a relation ManyToMany.

The schema and relation are well created.

However, when I edit or create a new product, I try to add a button where I can search a media file through the media library and a button to upload a new file.

For a relation OneToMany, this is easily done in `Admin\ProductAdmin::configureFormFields` by adding:

```
->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'required' => false
                ), array(
                    'link_parameters' => array(
                        'context'  => 'default',
                        'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'
                     )
                ))
```

So I get the same 3 icons as they already been used in the Gallery of SonataMediaBundle (*add from library*, *upload* and *delete*)

BUT
on the relation ManyToMany it isn't possible! Because every time I choose a media, it replaces the previous one. So I can't select multiple media types.

I thought on using the same way as The Gallery (`galleryHasMedia`)

```
->add('galleryHasMedias', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'by_reference' => false
        ), array(
            'edit'     => 'inline',
            'inline'   => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
            'link_parameters' => array('context' => $context)
        ))
```

However, it is really complex.
How can I choose or upload multiple media files on another Entity through a ManyToMany Relation?

Comment: What about `->add('image', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'multiple'=>true))`?

Comment: You can find sample demo [**`@sonata-media-upload-multiple-images`**](https://github.com/dianuj89/sonata-media-upload-multiple-images)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, but I've figured it out.

First of all, you might want to choose for a one-to-many/many-to-one relationship (using an intermediate entity) instead of a many-to-many relationship. Why? Because this allows for additional columns, such as a `position` column. This way you can reorder the images any way you want. In a many-to-many relationship, the link table only has two columns: the id's of the associated tables.

From the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional):

> (...) frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.

So I added this to my Product mapping file: (as you can see I'm using YAML as my configuration file format)

```
oneToMany:
    images:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\ProductImage
        mappedBy: product
        orderBy:
            position: ASC
```

And I created a new ProductImage mapping file:

```
MyBundle\Entity\ProductImage:
    type: entity
    table: product_images
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        position:
            type: integer
    manyToOne:
        product:
            targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Product
            inversedBy: images
        image:
            targetEntity: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
```

Using the command line (`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle`) I created / updated the corresponding entities (`Product` and `ProductImage`).

Next, I created/updated the Admin classes. ProductAdmin.php:

```
class ProductAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            // define other form fields
            ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable'  => 'position',
            ))
        ;
    }
```

ProductImageAdmin.php:

```
class ProductImageAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                'required' => false
            ), array(
                'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'product_image'
                )
            ))
            ->add('position', 'hidden')
        ;
    }
```

Don't forget to add both of them as services. If you don't want a link to the ProductImage form to be displayed on the dashboard, add the `show_in_dashboard: false` tag. (how you do this depends on the configuration format (yaml/xml/php) you use)

After this I had the admin form working correctly, however I still had some problems trying to save products. I had to perform the following steps in order to fix all problems:

First, I had to configure cascade persist operations for the Product entity. Again, how to do this depends on your configuration format. I'm using yaml, so in the `images` one-to-many relationship, I added the cascade property:

```
oneToMany:
    images:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\ProductImage
        mappedBy: product
        orderBy:
            position: ASC
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

That got it working (or so I thought), but I noticed that the `product_id` in the database was set to `NULL`. I solved this by adding `prePersist()` and `preUpdate()` methods to the `ProductAdmin` class:

```
public function prePersist($object)
{
    foreach ($object->getImages() as $image) {
        $image->setProduct($object);
    }
}

public function preUpdate($object)
{
    foreach ($object->getImages() as $image) {
        $image->setProduct($object);
    }
}
```

... and added a single line to the `addImages()` method of the `Product` entity:

```
public function addImage(\MyBundle\Entity\ProductImage $images)
{
    $images->setProduct($this);
    $this->images[] = $images;

    return $this;
}
```

This worked for me, now I can add, change, reorder, delete, etc. images to/from my Products.

Comment: Beautiful answer, your usage of the prePersist and preUpdate functions are perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rely on MediaBundle Gallery. In your entity you something like :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $images;
```

And then in your form, you'll be able to link a Gallery to your object with something like :

```
->add('images', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false), array('link_parameters' => array('context' => $context)))
```