# Field image is not linked to an admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have two entities: `Product` and `Image` and many Products can have many
Images so this generates a third table `ProductHasImages`. Entities are right
as `doctrine:schema:validate` command outputs:

```
Symfony > doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current
mapping file.
The command terminated with an error status (2)
```

I've added this lines to my `config.yml`:

```
services:
  tan.common.admin.image:
    class: Tan\CommonBundle\Admin\ImageAdmin
    tags:
      - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: "Imagenes",
show_in_dashboard: false }
    arguments: [null, Tan\CommonBundle\Entity\Image, null]
```

I've have the file `Tan\CommonBundle\Admin\ImageAdmin.php` created with the
following content:

```
<?php

namespace Tan\CommonBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class ImageAdmin extends Admin
{

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false));
    }

    public function prePersist($image)
    {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    public function preUpdate($image)
    {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    private function manageFileUpload($image)
    {
        if ($image->getFile()) {
            $image->refreshUpdated();
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to add the `image` field to `ProductAdmin.php` as follow:

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
    {

        $form
            ->add('product_name', null, array('label' => 'Nombre'))
            ->add('product_description', null, array('label' => 'Descripción'))
            ->add('image', 'sonata_type_admin', array('delete' => false));
    }
```

But any time I try to add a new product I get this error:

> The current field `image` is not linked to an admin. Please create one
>   for the target entity : ``

Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend you to use [SonataMediaBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/index.html#reference-guide) to handle multiple files

Comment: @tttony I tried that one at first but didn't get it to work, do you have any working example?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612966/sonata-media-bundle-relation-manytomany-in-entity-select-images) you have in the answers an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files the best in sonata admin use [**`Sonata Media Bundle`**](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html) to handle uploads and you can reuse them in your different admin once you have configured then your mapping will be

### Entities

- Products
- ProductHasImages

Now `Products` entity will have a mapping for `ProductHasImages` which can point many images *(Media files from sonata media bundle)* similar to

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\ProductHasImages", mappedBy="productImages",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
 */
protected $images;

other fields ...
```

Generate its getter and setter methods

```
removeImages()
getImages()
setImages()
addImages()
```

And now your junction entity i.e (`ProductHasImages`) will have a 2 mappings to point back `Products` and other one will point to `Sonata Media`

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $media;

/**
 * @var \Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Products
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Products", cascade={"persist","remove"} ,inversedBy="images", fetch="LAZY" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 */
protected $productImages;
```

Generate their getters and setters

Now create Admin class for `ProductHasImages`

which has a field in `configureFormFields` function

```
$formMapper->add('media', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false), array(
            'link_parameters' => $link_parameters
        )); //other fields too if you want to show in collection
```

And in your Product Admin class add this field

```
    ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'cascade_validation' => false,
            'type_options' => array('delete' => false),
        ), array(

            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
            'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'default'),
            'admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.product_has_images' 
      /*here provide service name for junction admin 
        like service code for admin defined for ProductHasImages */
        )
    )
```

You can find full code demo here [**`Git Hub`**](https://github.com/dianuj89/sonata-media-upload-multiple-images)